# repeat loop and produce new random number each time

Tags: python-3.x, loops, random

How can I get this code to repeat and num_1 & num_2 to generate a new random number until user types Q?

```
import random

num_1 = random.randrange(1, 15)
num_2 = random.randrange(1, 15)
score = 0

added = num_1 + num_2
while True:
    print("Press Q to quit anytime")
    answer = input("What is " + str(num_1) + " + " + str(num_2) + " = ")

    if answer == "q":
        print("Bye")
        break
    if added == int(answer):
        print("Great, try another one")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Try a new one")
```

Comment: might be worth looking in `f`-strings as they'd tidy your code up a lot. another minor point but you ask for `Q` but `q` is used to exit the program, think I'd fix that with a case-insensitive comparison, another useful thing to learn about

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring num_1 and num_2 with random. This sets them when you make the declaration so you're always adding the same two numbers. You're not assigning these to a function but a static return.

Comment: So it's not do-able?

Comment: It is doable - just trying not to literally write your code there as it's a concept that's valuable to learn yourself in how variables are declared and assigned.

Try adding print statements after each assignment and in your loop for what the values of num_1 and num_2 are - maybe that might help. Also, look up how functions work as that will also help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the values of `num_1` and `num_2` after each iteration. To do so you can add the following two lines

```py
    num_1 = random.randrange(1, 15)
    num_2 = random.randrange(1, 15)
```

at the end of the `while` loop.
You can also define a function that returns two random numbers and use it instead, something like this

```py
def get_two_random_numbers(lower=1, upper=15):
    return random.randrange(lower, higher), random.randrange(lower, higher)

num_1, num_2 = get_two_random_numbers()
```